# How to replace value with its column or rows index on condition in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

How to replace each value in the n x n array with column index if value >= 1 otherwise with row index.
Even better if the replaced value would map into other 1d array and return the value from it.

```
value_array = np.array([200, 200, 300, 10])

arr = np.array(
  [[1, 1, .66, 20],
   [1, 1, .66, 20],
   [1.5, 1.5, 1, 30],
   [.05, .05, .03, 1]]
)
```

Goal is to get an array of the same size containing values from value_array .
Examples:

- at position [0,2] the value is .66 which is less than 1 therefore row index is needed which is 0. 0 then is indexed into value_array and the answer in the result matrix position[0,2] is 200.
- at position [0,3] the value is 20 which is greater than 1 therefore column index is needed which is 3. 3 then is indexed into value_array and the answer in the result matrix position[0,3] is 10.

Also, this to be applied for a big array(1m x 1m) executions needs to be somehow split into multiple parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `numpy.select`:

```
conds = [arr>1, arr<1]
target = np.full(arr.shape, value_array)
np.select(conds, [target, target.T], arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[  1.,   1., 200.,  10.],
       [  1.,   1., 200.,  10.],
       [200., 200.,   1.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,   1.]])
```

Comment: You need `conds = [arr>=1, arr<1]` no ? otherwise the `1` remains.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for executing this on 1m x 1m matrix?

Comment: Split `arr` and `value_array` into submatrix, but we need more information about how those value are actually stored. If each value use 1 byte then your matrix should take ~1 Terabyte of data, this is what you have, a big file of 1 Terabyte ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `np.where`:

```
# I've rename value_array to v for simplicity.
# We use the broadcasting potential of numpy to get our result
res = np.where(arr>=1,v,v.reshape(len(v),1))
```

And `res=`

```
array([[200, 200, 200,  10],
       [200, 200, 200,  10],
       [200, 200, 300,  10],
       [ 10,  10,  10,  10]])
```

This solution also use less memory because you don't need to store intermediate result.